# Put a variable in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code for parse some `json` and make other things :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<script>

    $.getJSON(
        'http://sath3g.altervista.org/index.php', { get_param: 'value' }, 
        function(data) {
        // 'data' is an array of objects here
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        //data[i] is an individual line of excel data
            var lin = data[i]["Nr SAT"];



            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: '+ '<a href = http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html+?id='+lin '>'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"]+ '</a>'));

            $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data: '+ data[i]["Data"]));
            //http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html +?id=+lin

            }
        });
</script>

    <body>
        <header>

        </header>


    </body>

</html>
```

In the line of code below, I want to put in the link using variable `lin`. But it doesn't work.

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: '+ '<a href =http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html+?id='+lin '>'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"]+ '</a>'));
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `+` concatenation character after the `lin` variable. Try this:

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html+?id=' + lin + '">'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));
```

Better yet, build the DOM elements instead of concatenating ugly strings.

```
var $p = $('<p />');
var $a = $('<a />', { 
    href: 'http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html+?id=' + lin,
    text: data[i]["Nr SAT"]
});
$('body').append($p.append($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '+' after **lin**

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: '+ '<a href =http://sath3g.altervsta.org/jsonint.html+?id='+lin+'>'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"]+ '</a>'));
```